# Conflict between type alias and singleton object in the REPL

Tags: scala

I have code that defines a type alias for a trait and a singleton object for that type alias. When trying to work with these in the REPL though, I get some surprising errors.

This is the minimum amount of code with which I was able to reproduce the issue. Note that it's important that everything be split into different files, putting everything together seems to solve the problem.

`Decoder.scala`

```
package foo

trait Decoder[E, D] {
  def decode(e: E): D
}
```

`package.scala`

```
package object foo {
  type StringDecoder[A] = Decoder[String, A]
}
```

`StringDecoder.scala`

```
package foo

object StringDecoder {
  def apply[A](f: String => A): StringDecoder[A] = new StringDecoder[A] { override def decode(s: String) = f(s) }

  def apply[A](implicit da: StringDecoder[A]): StringDecoder[A] = da

  def foobar: Unit = println("foobar")
}
```

Here's a sample REPL session that exhibits the issue:

```
scala> import foo._
import foo._

scala> implicit val test: StringDecoder[Float] = StringDecoder(_.toFloat)
test: foo.StringDecoder[Float] = foo.StringDecoder$$anon$1@40a4337a

scala> StringDecoder.foobar
<console>:15: error: value foobar is not a member of object foo.StringDecoder
       StringDecoder.foobar
```

On the other hand, if I were not to refer to the type alias first, it works fine:

```
scala> import foo._
import foo._

scala> StringDecoder.foobar
foobar
```

My current interpretation is that the object is somehow shadowed by the type alias when the later is referenced before the former, but I really can't think of why that would happen. I've also failed to reproduce the issue outside of the REPL (or outside of [tut](https://github.com/tpolecat/tut), which is essentially the REPL).

Is there any known explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a known explanation? Not really, but it is a known issue ([SI-7139](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7139)).

In the comments on that issue Jason Zaugg suggests a workaround which would mean changing your `StringDecoder` to something like this:

```
package foo

object StringDecoder0 {
  ...
}
```

And then:

```
package object foo {
  type StringDecoder[A] = Decoder[String, A]
  val StringDecoder: StringDecoder0.type = StringDecoder0
}
```

This isn't a formal companion pair, but it supports the intended usage (as long as you don't have implicit instances defined in `StringDecoder0`).